# Operation returned an invalid status code 'Unauthorized' - Power bi embeded

Tags: azure, .net-core, powerbi, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-api

`Error Details: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Unauthorized' Microsoft.PowerBI.Api.ReportsOperations.GetReportInGroupWithHttpMessagesAsync(Guid groupId, Guid reportId, Dictionary\<string, List\<string\>\> customHeaders, CancellationToken cancellationToken) Microsoft.PowerBI.Api.ReportsOperationsExtensions.GetReportInGroupAsync(IReportsOperations operations, Guid groupId, Guid reportId, CancellationToken cancellationToken) testProjec.Services.PowerBiServiceApi.GetReport(Guid WorkspaceId, Guid ReportId) in       PowerBiServiceApi.cs \+ var report = await pbiClient.Reports.GetReportInGroupAsync(WorkspaceId, ReportId); testProjec.Controllers.HomeController.Embed() in HomeController.cs \+ var viewModel = await powerBiServiceApi.GetReport(workspaceId, reportId);`

I used dot net core and MVC
this error comes up I tried to embed power bi for customer
but the same error comes up i been trying to resolve this error for the last two days but i can't be solved

[microsoft powerbi dotnet manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-customer-app)

[microsoft powerbi html embed manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-sample-for-customers?tabs=net-core)
I

I tried seveal methods to resolve the problem like [enabling the power bi apis in powerbi settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpNNk.png) 
[giving permision in azure portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwiST.png)

eventhougt it don't work I'm getting the same error

is there any thingh i need to enable is there any steps I'm missing

I even tried embedding with the microsoft given sample code [microsoft example code](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples)

noting world I don't know what to do

Answer (score 0):

Operation returned an invalid status code 'Unauthorized' - Power bi embeded

> The error usually occurs if you missed granting access to **service principal** under your Power Bi workspace.

When I ran similar code without adding service principal under workspace, I too got **same error** *Operation returned an invalid status code ‘Unauthorized’*:

```c
var credentials = new TokenCredentials(accessToken, "Bearer");
var client = new PowerBIClient(new Uri(apiUrl), credentials);

var groupIdGuid = Guid.Parse("groupId");
var reportIdGuid = Guid.Parse("reportId");

var report = client.Reports.GetReportInGroup(groupIdGuid, reportIdGuid);

Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("Report ID: " + report.Id);
Console.WriteLine("Report Name: " + report.Name);
Console.WriteLine("Report Web URL: " + report.WebUrl);
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **resolve** the error, make sure to add the service principal under your Power Bi workspace with proper access like below:

[image]

When I ran the code again after few minutes, I got the **response** successfully with report details:

```c
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using Microsoft.PowerBI.Api;
using Microsoft.Rest;

var clientId = "appId";
var clientSecret = "secret";
var scope = "https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default";

var apiUrl = "https://api.powerbi.com/";
var groupId = "groupId";
var reportId = "reportId";

var app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
    .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
    .WithAuthority(new Uri("https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId"))
    .Build();
var result = app.AcquireTokenForClient(new string[] { scope }).ExecuteAsync().Result;
var accessToken = result.AccessToken;

var credentials = new TokenCredentials(accessToken, "Bearer");
var client = new PowerBIClient(new Uri(apiUrl), credentials);

var groupIdGuid = Guid.Parse(groupId);
var reportIdGuid = Guid.Parse(reportId);

var report = client.Reports.GetReportInGroup(groupIdGuid, reportIdGuid);

Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("Report ID: " + report.Id);
Console.WriteLine("Report Name: " + report.Name);
Console.WriteLine("Report Web URL: " + report.WebUrl);
```

**Response:**

[image]

**Reference:**
[Embed content in your Power BI embedded analytics application | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-sample-for-customers?tabs=net-core#step-7---enable-workspace-access)